# can I have 2 functions in google.script.run?

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications

Can I have multiple apps script function in google.script.run like:

`google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function).scriptfunction1(variable).scriptfunction2(variable);`

Comment: Questions edits should not invalidate answers. If you need clarification or provide feedback regading an answer, post a comment in the corresponding answer. I you need to do a follow-up question, instead of editing an already answered question post a new question.

Answer (score 1):

No. The `.scriptfunction1(variable)` function cannot return a script runner. It can only return a value, an object or array that ultimately contains primitives, or `undefined`.

But you can do something like this (from the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication#script_runners)):

```js
const myRunner = google.script.run.withFailureHandler(onFailure);
const myRunner1 = myRunner.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess);
const myRunner2 = myRunner.withSuccessHandler(onDifferentSuccess);

myRunner1.doSomething();
myRunner1.doSomethingElse();
myRunner2.doSomething();
```